# Using xargs to construct a find command that excludes a list of directories from an environment variable

Tags: find, xargs

I know how to exclude certain directories from `find`: `find <path> ! -path <path to exclude>`. But this can be too tedious to type out when I need to exclude a lot of directories or simply cannot be used when the list of directories I need to exclude are not known ahead of time.

So, say I have a list of directories stored in a variable. Can I use `xargs` to construct a `find` command that excludes each of these directories? If so, how?

Comment: are we talking a "basic" shell variable like `v='file1 file2 file3'` or something more complex, like a bash array?

Comment: did [the below](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/263669/117549) answer your question?

Answer (score 0):

For the 'simple' variable case; note that the directories can't contain whitepace, as that's what separates them inside the variable.

```
excludes='dir1 dir2 dir3'
findexcl=
set -f
for p in $excludes
do
  findexcl="$findexcl ! -path $p"
done
echo find ... $findexcl ...
```